# VB2005 Find/Search in a ListOf Structure

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, find, generic-list

VB2005: I've been looking for several hours on a good example and i found some but unfortunately they are for VB2008+. Im currently working in VB2005 so it seems like this was harder to do in that release.

I have a class for a point

```
Public Class cPoint
    Public Speed As Integer
    Public Alt As Integer
    Public Status As String = ""
    Public Err As String = ""
End Class
```

I populate a list of points with MyPoints=List(of cPoint). Now all i need to do is find the first match with a supplied speed and alt. I tried

```
Dim p As cPoint = MyPoints.Find(Function(item As cPoint) item.Speed = 85)
```

But that doesn't work in VB2005 much less work with more than 1 filter. I just cant seem to find a good example that works in VB2005. I could iterate through the list but its kind of big and not very efficient. Any tips on how i can do this in VB2005?

~agp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.Net 2005 lacks lambda support hence that style of query won't work.  The simplest version that will is to manually iterate with a `For Each` loop.

```
My p As cPoint = Nothing
For Each item in MyPoints 
  If item.Speed = 85 Then
    p = item
    Exit For 
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Yep and Ive tried that but my list is kind of big and I have to hit it numerous times. there's got to be a better way. I'm looking at some samples but cant quite get how to do it properly, other than iteration.

Comment: @sinDizzy this solution is just as fast as the one in your post.  The use the same basic logic under the hood.

Comment: really? thought I had read that using anonymous delegates was significantly faster. Im gonna stick with the loop for now unless I find a better way. thanks.

Comment: @sinDizzy it can be faster in certain micro benchmark situations and possibly in some real world applications.  You'd have to profile your individual app to see if it was a factor here.  Although I'd seriously doubt it.

Comment: I ran the app and i didn't have as many look-ups as I thought so it actually ran pretty fast. many thanks for the info and advice.